# Adding .ashx as a web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

For my application, I'm currently using a webservice to retrieve some information I need in XML format. The way I'm doing it now is via a HTTP web request, so the code looks something like this:

```
serviceURL = "http://longurl/webservice.ashx?apikey=key&action=getDetail&id=ID";

HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();

dataXML.Load(HttpWResp.GetResponseStream());
```

I feel that including the entire URL inside my code looks really clunky, so I've thought of adding the web service as a web reference. However, I came across this error when trying to add the web reference:

> The document at the url longurl/webservice.ashx was not recognized as a known document type.
>   The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>   - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL longurl/webservice.ashx could not be found.'.
>     - The document format is not recognized.
>   - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (2, 2).'.
>     -  was not expected.
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be  and its namespace should be ''.'.

Am I missing any steps that I had to do before attempting to add the web service? Or is this a problem with the web service itself?

I'd also appreciate any advice on alternative methods to code this a bit more elegantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly just put that url in an AppSetting.

so that serviceURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceUrl"];

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Comment: Ah, cool. This seems like a good way to move the clunky stuff over. I'd probably have to take a look into encrypting the sensitive data stored inside though.

Thanks.

Comment: Well... I think they already thought of that. You can encrypt configuration sections in the application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx

Mind you that with Reflector any string you put in code is pretty much available to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

A "web reference" is intended for an "old-style" ASMX web service, a "service reference" for a WCF service. You can't use (or abuse) that functionality for what you're trying to do.

Either just put your URL into config as "Min" suggested, or then change to a real WCF service. With the WCF Rest Starter Kit, you can create these types of "HTTP Plain Old XML (POX)" services quite easily - see the [Pluralsight screencast](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/screencasts/screencast.aspx?id=http-plain-xml-services) on that topic for more information.

Marc

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll definitely take a closer look at that tutorial video you've linked to and see what it has to offer.

Comment: @Min: because Min as such could be misinterpreted as "minimum" - putting it in quotes should make it clear that it's a name of someone else who answered the question.

Comment: The videos have been removed and the WCF Starter Kit doesn't exist anymore per se - [read an excellent article on it by Aaron Skonnard on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx). Sorry, I don't have a new link for those videos...